# How to Run Powershell script as admin using code?

Tags: powershell

I have created a PowerShell Script which is on the DC, however I when I run commands from my script it is not running as Admin.

Below is the code I am using to run the code as admin, but this does not seem to be working as I have to manually open PowerShell as Admin then Browse to the Script. Can someone please check the below and give any suggestions.

```
PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command "& {Start-Process PowerShell -ArgumentList '-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File ""C:\Scripts\SuperScript.ps1""' -Verb RunAs}";
```

Comment: As an aside: No need to wrap your command in `& { ... }` (older versions of the docs mistakenly suggested that that's necessary).

Comment: Where are you running this from? Are you saying the `Start-Process` command is ignored altogether, or that it only opens a new window without executing the script? Please clarify by _directly updating your question_ - please don't respond with a comment.

Comment: I am running this direct from the AD server. Yes I did have Start-Process however this did not solve the issue:  
PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command "& {Start-Process PowerShell -ArgumentList '-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File ""C:\Scripts\SuperScript.ps1""' -Verb RunAs}";
Start-Process powershell.exe -argument C:\Scripts\SuperScript.ps1" -Verb RunAs

Comment: Code in comments is hard to read, which is why I suggested you update your question itself with clarifications. I still don't understand what the problem is or what you're trying to achieve, but perhaps someone else will. Perhaps [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) can help with updating your question.